# Strange behavior in Entity Framework with a list

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an winforms order taking app for a restaurant. On startup I read the list of products available as this:

```
var products = context.Products.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(p => p.Id).ToList();
```

When the user clicks the button corresponding to a menu Item, I identify the product to be added to the order like this:

```
var product = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == menuItem.ProductId);
var orderItem = new OrderItem
{
    ProductId = product.Id,
    Quantity = 1,
    UnitPrice = product.Price,
    ListValue = 1 * product.Price,
    Product = product
};
```

Here is the OrderItem entity:

```
public partial class OrderItem
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalValue { get; set; }

    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

After saving the order, some strange things happen (for me anyway): The product in the list changes its Id, as if it is a new product, with the same attributes. Also after `context.SaveChanges()` in the database I will have 2 rows of the same product.

Anyone can point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you include definition of OrderItem entity? The problem is probably in that Product = product line... especially since you are getting those products with AsNoTracking().

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211680/what-difference-does-asnotracking-make

Comment: The behaviour is the same if I remove `AsNoTracking()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have obtained the list of products as NoTracking.
But then you assign it to the product in the orderitem, effectively pulling the object back in.
If you just leave out that statement and do this instead

```
var product = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == menuItem.ProductId);
var orderItem = new OrderItem
{
    ProductId = product.Id,
    Quantity = 1,
    UnitPrice = product.Price,
    ListValue = 1 * product.Price,
    //Product = product don't do this
};
```

then it will work ok.

Comment: I was using `product` in `orderItem` to display its name. Should I use a different way to display the product name in orderItem?

Comment: You can solve that by creating a simple translation function that translates the id to the name by using your products variable.The thing is that the product is really defined by the id. And you should not have to pull in the product if your original idea was to use notracking.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try. My idea to not use tracking for the products was to avoid frequent database calls, since the products list does not change while application is running.

Comment: using notracking saves memory because there is no change tracking on those objects. A perfect fit for what you want. Please at least upvote peoples answers that tried to help you. ;-) You can also mark your own answer as answer so it is clear that the problem is solved.

Comment: It worked, finally! After one whole day. Thanks @Philip!

Answer (score 1):

When you `Add` the `Order`, the `Product` is also changed to `Added`. You can simply prevent this by removing the assignment

```
Product = product
```

It is enough to set `ProductId`.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. But I need the `Product.Name` to display in the UI. I solved it by reattaching the `products` to the new context when saving.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the question @Jehof mentioned, I solved it by reattaching the `products` to the new context in which `SaveChanges()` occurs:

```
products.ForEach(p => context.Products.Attach(p));
context.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: that looks more like a patch than a solution.

Comment: The reason i think it is a patch is that you are attaching all products. This is clearly a workaround to the real problem.