# How to solve performance issue when pagination in .net mvc?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, pagination, pagedlist

I'm using PagedList.MVC nuget,
and it takes almost 10 seconds each time I clicked on the next button.
I have seen that there are around 350,000 results in the PagedList and each time I clicked on the next button, it goes through all the results again. How should I solve this?

Here is the code.

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
        {
            List<Item> items;
            using (var db = new DBDevEntities())
            {
                items= db.items.ToList(); 
            }

            var pageNumber = page ?? 1;

            return View(items.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 25));
        }
```

Comment: Do not use `List<Item>` and `.ToList()` (that is loading all records into memory before you do the paging

Comment: You're loading your entire list every time you page. Cache the value of `items` into a property of your controller (or better yet, implement paging server-side).

Comment: @stephenmuecke You should use it?

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh, Use what? (it needs to be `IQueryable<T>`, not `List<T>`)

Comment: @stephenmuecke I mean use other frameworks.

Comment: @stephenmuecke also  use `AsNoTracking() ` in your code. Ex :  `db.itemsAsNoTracking().ToList();  ` Also see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211680/what-difference-does-asnotracking-make)

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh, That is not necessary

Comment: @stephenmuecke So if i'm using entity framework in db first mode. How should I get an IQueryble<item>? I have tried var items= db.items; then return View(items.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 25)); there is an error The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.

Comment: `var items` is fine, you just need to add an `OrderBy()` in your query - e.g. `var items = db.items.OrderBy(x => x.someProperty)`

Comment: @stephenmuecke It worked good! Now it's much faster than before! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`db.items.ToList();` is loading all 350,000 records into memory, and then you are filtering on that in code.  You need to do the pagination database-side using `.Skip()` and `.Take()`.

Edit: Apparently PagedList.MVC takes care of this, you just need to keep it as in `IQueryable` and not call `.ToList()`.  From https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public object Index(int? page)
    {
        var products = MyProductDataSource.FindAllProducts(); //returns IQueryable<Product> representing an unknown number of products. a thousand maybe?

        var pageNumber = page ?? 1; // if no page was specified in the querystring, default to the first page (1)
        var onePageOfProducts = products.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 25); // will only contain 25 products max because of the pageSize

        ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts = onePageOfProducts;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: `.ToPagedList()` is using `.Skip()` and `.Take()` :)

Comment: You should be careful that you don't dispose of the DbContext before running ToPagedList() though.

Comment: So if i'm using entity framework in db first mode. How should I get an IQueryble<item>? I have tried var items= db.items; then return View(items.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 25)); there is an error The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'. @Paul Abbott