# EF Core tracked entities not being saved

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm accessing my db instance via dependency injection, which is scoped to the request.

Here's the code from my `startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApiEntity"));
            options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
        });

    services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

In my `index.cshtml.cs` file, I have a list of projects that I want to update. I'm binding them to the PageModel like so:

```
    [BindProperty]
    public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
```

When the `OnPost` method is called with the updated entities and I run `_context.SaveChanges();` the tracked entities do not get updated.

When I try updating the entities first by calling: `_context.UpdateRange(Projects);` I get the following error:

> **InvalidOperationException**: The instance of entity type 'Project' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ProjectId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values

I've looked at other examples of this error messages and the solution seems to be to [scope your repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48202403/instance-of-entity-type-cannot-be-tracked-because-another-instance-with-same-key) (which I already am) or to [detach your entity and then reattach it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856073/the-instance-of-entity-type-cannot-be-tracked-because-another-instance-of-this-t) but I'm not sure why I would add this additional complexity. I should be able to update the entities that are being tracked by simply calling `_context.saveChanges`. Is this possible ? If so, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: we need your code that is handling the POST and doing the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. I'm keeping this up for other weary developers:

In my `cshtml.cs` file, I was assigning  `Projects` in the constructor function:

```
    public ProjectsPageModel(AppDbContext _context)
    {
        this._context = _context;
        Projects = _context.Projects.ToList();
    }
```

When I removed the db call from the constructor function and put the call in the `OnGet` method instead, I was able to successfully update the db by:

```
         _context.UpdateRange(Projects);
         _context.SaveChanges();
```