# Data (json) from URL already has id. How to add the data to the database using Entity Framework

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to add or update data in database from url (json), but this data already has the id value.

JSON file

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "first_name": "Tony",
        "last_name": "Stark",
        "date": "2008-07-06"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "David",
        "last_name": "Guetta",
        "date": "2008-08-05"
    },
...
```

Model

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Controller `Index` method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    string json;

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
       json = client.GetStringAsync(Url).Result;
    }

    var people = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);

    if (people is not null)
    {
        await _context.AddRangeAsync(people);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    return _context.People != null ?
                View(await _context.People.ToListAsync()) :
                Problem("Entity set 'ApplicationDbContext.People'  is null.");
}
```

After loading this page, the error shows up, problem with the key and id. I know that the problem is that json data has the `id` values, but I don't know how to avoid that. Is there any solution. How to keep id values from json and tell the database "please, don't generate the id values, take the `id` values from my converted json file"

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Person' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
> Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I do not think that the id is your problem, unless it is not unique in the input data. Have a look here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48202403/instance-of-entity-type-cannot-be-tracked-because-another-instance-with-same-key, there are many ptoposed solutions.

Comment: " I want to add or update data" ??? to add needs different code then to update. You have to decide what do you want

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the solution. It has been required another data annotation. So the Sql server will not increment the `Id`

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

Model

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

And then the method that actually do the add or update data, because if the table is already populated it truncate the table first.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUpToDateData()
{
    string json;
    using (HttpClient client = new())
    {
        json = client.GetStringAsync(Url).Result;
    }

    var people = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);

    if (people is not null)
    {
        await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("TRUNCATE TABLE [People]");
        await _context.AddRangeAsync(people);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```