# Transient service with a function that runs only for the first request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my asp.net core 6 mvc project, I have a transient service `ContentService`. This service is inherited from `IContentService` and added to `Program.cs` using

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IContentService, ContentService>();
```

Here is the implementation of the service:

```
public interface IContentService
{
    public string GetText(int id);
}

public class ContentService : IContentService
{
    private readonly ContentDbContext _context;
    private List<string> textList;

    public ContentService(ContentDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

        ReadTexts();
    }

    public void ReadTexts()
    {
        // Reads text from the database and fills the textList.
        // THIS CODE MUST RUN ONLY FOR THE FIRST REQUEST.
    }

    public string GetText(int id)
    {
        return textList(id);
    }
}
```

The problem is every time `ContentService` is requested, the constructor runs and `ReadTexts()` is called, which is a heavy function that must only run for the first request. **Is there anyway to implement a transient service with a code block that runs only for the first request?** Note that I cannot use `AddSingleton`.

Comment: any specific reason why can't you use AddSingleton. it is for such purpose only.

Comment: @CodingMytra Occasionally I need to edit some text within the database, and if I want to use AddSingleton, the database also needs to be defined as Singleton. In this situation, I run into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48202403).

Comment: Seems conceptionally wrong to put a heavy load function into the constructor to be honest. If you really need to do something like this, a more DI-way might be to use in-memory cache to keep a state that the function has run. Or separate the "loading" into a warmup function that is only running once when the application starts - depends on you use-case...

Comment: @Mario could you explain more about "separate the loading into a warmup function"?

Comment: @Jaber I used the following code in an adjusted way in our projects https://github.com/thomaslevesque/AspNetCore.AsyncInitialization/tree/master/src/AspNetCore.AsyncInitialization you can call `await host.InitAsync();` and have as many initializer as you need. The pipeline starts accepting requests only afterwards which is nice. But it depends if thats what you are searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make textList as static if you want it to hold data which should be read only on first request.

try this.

```
public class ContentService : IContentService
{
    private readonly ContentDbContext _context;
    private static List<string> textList = new List<string>();

    public ContentService(ContentDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

        ReadTexts();
    }

    public void ReadTexts()
    {
       if(!textList.Any())
       {
        // Reads text from the database and fills the textList.
        // THIS CODE MUST RUN ONLY FOR THE FIRST REQUEST.
       }
    }

    public string GetText(int id)
    {
        return textList(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a more dependency-injection-way?

Comment: does it solve you problem you asked in question ? if you want in-memory caching then that will be a totally different solution.

Comment: yes it does, but I'm curious about other solutions.

Comment: check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for implementing in-memory caching