# Entity Framework Core: Issue with Tracking Multiple Instances of the Same Entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on an ASP.NET Core application using Entity Framework Core for data access. I am encountering an issue when trying to edit a FiscalYear entity in my database. I have the following code:

```
public async Task<Response> EditFiscalYear(FiscalYear fiscalYear)
{
    try
    {
        var validate = await EditFiscalYearValidate(new FiscalYearValidationModel { Object = fiscalYear });
        if (validate.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            return validate;
_context.EditEntity(fiscalYear);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return SuccessResponse(resultObject: fiscalYear, resultText: "Fiscal Year Updated Successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return FaultResponse(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And the validation method is:

```
public async Task<Response> EditFiscalYearValidate(FiscalYearValidationModel model)
{
    if ((await _context.PayPeriods
            .AnyAsync(x => x.FiscalYearId == model.Object.FiscalYearId)))
    {
        return FaultResponse("Fiscal Year Dependency found");
    }

    var fiscalYear = await _context.FiscalYears.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.FiscalYearId == model.Object.FiscalYearId);

    if (fiscalYear is null)
        return NotFoundResponse("No Fiscal Year Found");

    // Other validation checks...

    return SuccessResponse();
}
```

Here is the EditEntity function for more clarity:

```
  public void EditEntity<TEntity>(TEntity entity, List<string> excludedParams = null)
        {
            var entry = this.Entry(entity);
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;

            //some other modifications
        }
```

When I try to edit a FiscalYear entity, I get the following exception:

"The instance of entity type 'FiscalYear' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'FiscalYearId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values."

I understand that EF Core is complaining because it's trying to track two instances of the same entity at the same time. However, I'm puzzled because when I don't store the result of FirstOrDefaultAsync in a variable, I don't get the exception:

```
await _context.FiscalYears.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.FiscalYearId == model.Object.FiscalYearId);
```

Why does this happen?

As a solution I am currently doing

```
 var fiscalYear = _context.FiscalYears.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.FiscalYearId == model.Object.FiscalYearId);
```

This solves my problem but I still don't understand why the tracking behaviour doesn't manifest in the same manner for

```
await _context.FiscalYears.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.FiscalYearId == model.Object.FiscalYearId);
```

Comment: What is `_context.EditEntity(fiscalYear);`?

Comment: Taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48204159/7450780)?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv added the EditEntity description

Comment: Well, why you even change stage of the Entry? EF Core automatically tracks changes, so just modify properties and do not touch anything else.

Comment: @DenisMicheal.k I don't have the same problem, my main question is related to why storing the result of the FirstOrDefaultAsync query in variable causes EFCore to track the entity but if I don't store it then it seemingly doesn't track ? Or even if it does track, doesn't cause a tracking conflict

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I am building upon legacy work and currently for some reason cannot change this. Our system is already mud of ball microservices, so have to achieve my goals with minimum changes.

Comment: Use tracked entities and do not play with Entries, just modify properties and everything should go smoothly.

Comment: *"when I don't store the result of FirstOrDefaultAsync in a variable, I don't get the exception*" No way. Please don't waste your time with meaningless tests. Either use no tracking query, or work with tracked entity once you get it from db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`var fiscalYear = await _context.FiscalYears.`**AsNoTracking()**`.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.FiscalYearId == model.Object.FiscalYearId);` in `EditFiscalYearValidate` method. As far as I see you are loading two entities with the same primary key in your DbContext.

At first you are loading and attaching the `FiscalYear` entity to the database context  here `var fiscalYear = await _context.FiscalYears.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.FiscalYearId == model.Object.FiscalYearId);` and then essentially you are attaching the same entity again a second time here

```
 var entry = this.Entry(entity);
        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Adding `AsNoTracking()` to the first query will prevent entity framework from tracking the FiscalYear entity in the `DBContext` at first. Since you are only reading the data and not updating this entity in the `EditFiscalYearValidate` method there is no need for EF to track it's state. This way in `EditEntity` the entity will be tracked as modified for the first time in your `DbContext` and EF won't complain that you are attaching the same entity to same instance of the `DbContext` twice. More on entity tracking you can read in the official Microsoft docs on the topic https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

Answer (score 2):

This is the detached entity trap.

```
public async Task<Response> EditFiscalYear(FiscalYear fiscalYear)
```

The data passed into this method is merely *cast* as an entity. It is a detached instance that will not be associated with your DbContext.

Later in your code you are telling the DbContext to fetch an existing FiscalYear:

```
var fiscalYear = await _context.FiscalYears.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.FiscalYearId == model.Object.FiscalYearId);

if (fiscalYear is null)
    return NotFoundResponse("No Fiscal Year Found");
```

At this point, the DbContext will be tracking an instance of the entity for that fiscal year.

After this, trying to execute:

```
var entry = this.Entry(entity);
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
```

... passing the "phony" fiscalState entity passed into the method will attempt to attach that phony entity to the DbContext. The context is already tracking a reference, so you get the complaint.

Using `AsNoTracking()` when querying the FiscalState for the validation will appear to fix the problem, but it isn't fixing anything. You honestly should **not** be updating data this way.

```
// _context.EditEntity(fiscalYear); <- never do this with a detached entity you cannot guarantee the quality of.
```

... Instead: (long way)

```
var existingFiscalYear = _context.FiscalYears.Single(x => x.FiscalYearId == fiscalYear.FiscalYearId);
existingFiscalYear.SomeAllowedValue = fiscalYear.SomeAllowedValue;
//... copy across all allowed values to update...
_context.SaveChanges();
```

... or short way with Automapper / mapper:

```
var existingFiscalYear = _context.FiscalYears.Single(x => x.FiscalYearId == fiscalYear.FiscalYearId);
_mapper.Map(fiscalYear, existingFiscalYear);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

... where the Mapper is configured with knowing what is allowed to be copied from object to object so only expected data is copied across.

The main problems with doing the EntityState.Modified approach with detached entities, is the already tracking error you are getting, and also that you are trusting the data coming in entirely. If this is something like an API or web Controller method where the data coming in is just serialize values, it can be tampered with by mischievous or malicious users, or bugs in the client-side code leading to values being updated you don't intend to be changed. It's also inefficient as this will always generate an UPDATE statement with *all* fields whether they changed or not. Editing a tracked instance instead will only generate an UPDATE statement if something changed, and only for the fields that changed.

If you do trust a detached entity and want to update it, you must always check the DbContext's local tracking cache for existing entities in case a reference happens to be attached. If you find one then you either have to detach it first (potentially losing changes) or perform the copy-over-approach. Checking for a tracked instance is done by looking at the `.Local` of the DbSet:

```
var trackedInstance = _context.FiscalYears.Local.FirstOrDefailt(x => x.FiscalYearId == fiscalYear.FiscalYearId)
```

if this returns something, you can copy values across. If it doesn't then you can attach this instance. (Again, provided you can 100% trust the detached instance is complete and correct)