# Using UpdateAsync method of UserManager throws InvalidOperationException on EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, invalidoperationexception, usermanager

I am in the process of updating a dotnet Framework project to dotnet Core. I have a `UserProfileService` class to handle all the users. This had a `UserManager` which is injected using the dotnet core dependency injection.

When I try to update a `UserProfile` (which is a class that is derived from `IdentityUser`) is throws the following `InvalidOperationException`  error:

```
The instance of entity type 'UserProfile' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: GUID}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
```

The `dbContext` is connected using the following code in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddIdentityCore<UserProfile>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AvgContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I am not getting this user from the context before this call, so it seems very unlikely that this would happen.

Does anybody know what could be the case?

Comment: Do you have a [mre]? Can you please share some invocation code and how do you get `UserProfile` instance you pass to update method?

Comment: Are you reusing the dbcontext? This answer on a similar question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48204159/10463678

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856073/the-instance-of-entity-type-cannot-be-tracked-because-another-instance-of-this-t)

Answer (score 0):

> I am not getting this user from the context before this call

Directly, maybe not. Indirectly, this still counts.  If you are using a DbContext to load the user entity you should always verify whether an entity is tracked before using `Update` or `Attach`:

```
var trackedUser = _dbContext.Users.Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId);
```

if trackedUser comes back with a value you should copy the data across to it and call SaveChanges, otherwise you can consider attaching or using `Update`, though I generally recommend always loading the entity in an update scenario as this asserts the entity exists, and you can check any current concurrency flags (I.e. RowVersion/Timestamp) before apply a possibly stale update.

As a simple rule, avoid using `Update`/`UpdateAsync`. when working with DbContext. UserManager offers a bit of a wrapper around EF, but still aim to copy values across.

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
// Copy values across based on what is allowed to be updated.
user.Email = dto.Email; // etc.
await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```

If you are using a DbContext directly to access a User entity:

```
var user = await _dbContext.Users.SingleAsync(x => x.UserId == userId);
// copy values across based on what is allowed to be updated.
user.Email = dto.Email; // etc.
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```