# C# & EF Core: database entry error -> cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a problem with inserting rows of data into my database using EF Core. I want to insert an CySe row with default option from database (see JSON).

On the second line of code in the `PUT`

```
dbContext.Entry(cySeMainFeatures.computer).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

I get an error, because every column has the same option, as I want it.

Json: https://127.0.0.1:7128/NIST/CySeMainFeatures - PUT with Body

```
{"id":0,"networkConnectedId":0,"networkConnected":{"id":1,"name":"None"},"networkLevelId":0,"networkLevel":{"id":1,"name":"None"},"computerId":0,"computer":{"id":1,"name":"None"},"localUserInterfaceId":0,"localUserInterface":{"id":1,"name":"None"},"remoteUserInterfaceId":0,"remoteUserInterface":{"id":1,"name":"None"},"userAccountsId":0,"userAccounts":{"id":1,"name":"None"},"wirelessCommunicationId":0,"wirelessCommunication":{"id":1,"name":"None"},"multipleIPConnectionsId":0,"multipleIPConnections":{"id":1,"name":"None"},"communicatesAcrossNetworksId":0,"communicatesAcrossNetworks":{"id":1,"name":"None"},"logFilesSupportedId":0,"logFilesSupported":{"id":1,"name":"None"},"userAccountLockingAccordingToRequirementsId":0,"userAccountLockingAccordingToRequirements":{"id":1,"name":"None"}}
```

Error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: the instance of entity type 'Option' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values

I get it working, but just with new option entries like:

```
id - name
1 - None
2 - none
...
```

But that is not what I want to have.

I want in every col. of CySe "1-None" option

Thank you for your help

**UPDATE**

I created a small Project for this case:

https://github.com/No0b7/RestAPIError

**FIX**

Thank you guys, with your help i was able to fix the Problem.

It's not pretty but i have to check the Database and get the result from the database to insert it.

```
        [HttpPut()]
        public IActionResult Put(CySeMainFeatures cySeMainFeatures)
        {
            try
            {
                var communicatesAcrossNetworks = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == cySeMainFeatures.communicatesAcrossNetworks.name && x.id == cySeMainFeatures.communicatesAcrossNetworks.id);
                if(communicatesAcrossNetworks == null)
                {
                    communicatesAcrossNetworks = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 1);
                }
                cySeMainFeatures.communicatesAcrossNetworks = communicatesAcrossNetworks;

                var computer = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == cySeMainFeatures.computer.name && x.id == cySeMainFeatures.computer.id);
                if(computer == null)
                {
                    computer = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 1);
                }
                cySeMainFeatures.computer = computer;

                var localUserInterface = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == cySeMainFeatures.localUserInterface.name && x.id == cySeMainFeatures.localUserInterface.id);
                if(localUserInterface == null)
                {
                    localUserInterface = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 1);
                }
                cySeMainFeatures.localUserInterface = localUserInterface;

                var logFilesSupported = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == cySeMainFeatures.logFilesSupported.name && x.id == cySeMainFeatures.logFilesSupported.id);
                if(logFilesSupported == null)
                {
                    logFilesSupported = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 1);
                }
                cySeMainFeatures.logFilesSupported = logFilesSupported;

                var multipleIPConnections = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == cySeMainFeatures.multipleIPConnections.name && x.id == cySeMainFeatures.multipleIPConnections.id);
                if(multipleIPConnections == null)
                {
                    multipleIPConnections = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 1);
                }
                cySeMainFeatures.multipleIPConnections = multipleIPConnections;

                var networkConnected = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == cySeMainFeatures.networkConnected.name && x.id == cySeMainFeatures.networkConnected.id);
                if(networkConnected == null)
                {
                    networkConnected = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 1);
                }
                cySeMainFeatures.networkConnected = networkConnected;

                var networkLevel = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == cySeMainFeatures.networkLevel.name && x.id == cySeMainFeatures.networkLevel.id);
                if(networkLevel == null)
                {
                    networkLevel = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 1);
                }
                cySeMainFeatures.networkLevel = networkLevel;

                var remoteUserInterface = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == cySeMainFeatures.remoteUserInterface.name && x.id == cySeMainFeatures.remoteUserInterface.id);
                if(remoteUserInterface == null)
                {
                    remoteUserInterface = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 1);
                }
                cySeMainFeatures.remoteUserInterface = remoteUserInterface;

                var userAccountLockingAccordingToRequirements = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == cySeMainFeatures.userAccountLockingAccordingToRequirements.name && x.id == cySeMainFeatures.userAccountLockingAccordingToRequirements.id);
                if(userAccountLockingAccordingToRequirements == null)
                {
                    userAccountLockingAccordingToRequirements = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 1);
                }
                cySeMainFeatures.userAccountLockingAccordingToRequirements = userAccountLockingAccordingToRequirements;

                var userAccounts = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == cySeMainFeatures.userAccounts.name && x.id == cySeMainFeatures.userAccounts.id);
                if(userAccounts == null)
                {
                    userAccounts = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 1);
                }
                cySeMainFeatures.userAccounts = userAccounts;

                var wirelessCommunication = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == cySeMainFeatures.wirelessCommunication.name && x.id == cySeMainFeatures.wirelessCommunication.id);
                if(wirelessCommunication == null)
                {
                    wirelessCommunication = dbContext.NIST_Option.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 1);
                }
                cySeMainFeatures.wirelessCommunication = wirelessCommunication;

                dbContext.Entry(cySeMainFeatures.communicatesAcrossNetworks).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                dbContext.Entry(cySeMainFeatures.computer).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                dbContext.Entry(cySeMainFeatures.localUserInterface).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                dbContext.Entry(cySeMainFeatures.logFilesSupported).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                dbContext.Entry(cySeMainFeatures.multipleIPConnections).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                dbContext.Entry(cySeMainFeatures.networkConnected).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                dbContext.Entry(cySeMainFeatures.networkLevel).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                dbContext.Entry(cySeMainFeatures.remoteUserInterface).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                dbContext.Entry(cySeMainFeatures.userAccountLockingAccordingToRequirements).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                dbContext.Entry(cySeMainFeatures.userAccounts).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                dbContext.Entry(cySeMainFeatures.wirelessCommunication).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                dbContext.Add(cySeMainFeatures);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
                var location = Url.Action(nameof(cySeMainFeatures), new { cySeMainFeatures.id }) ?? $"/{cySeMainFeatures.id}";
                return Created(location, cySeMainFeatures);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.InnerException.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Maybe you guys have a more beautiful answer for this code, but this works.

Thank you all for Helping

Comment: Does this answer your question? [instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with same key value is tracked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48202403/instance-of-entity-type-cannot-be-tracked-because-another-instance-with-same-key)

Comment: Please show this a a [mre], with an emphasis on *minimal*. That said, it seems that first you have to make sure that before attaching, all Option references point to only one instance having value "1-None".

Comment: A suggestion about http methods found in your code. The POST method is intended for inserting new items, and the PUT method is for update actions. In your code it seems that they are used coutrariwise. This is not a big issue if it is a personal project, but if your API is used by someone else it could be an issue. See [HTTP Request Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods).

Comment: @Progman Sadly not, my Program.cs is different as u can see in github now and DBContext ServiceLifetime is set to scoped already

Comment: @GertArnold Done, Thank you. They pointing all to the same db Entry, even if they give the correct name with an different id, they will get the correct id-name combination from the Database. and that seems like to be the problem, because he want to save in all option cases the identical option (1,None)

Comment: @RobertoFerraris Thank you for this info, yeah i switched it accidently, thanks for the info, its a private project, but sure i will change it

Comment: Post your code in the question itself. This error is caused by an application error - the code tried to *attach* two detached objects that had the same key, or it tried to attach an object when it had already loaded another with the same key. There's no reason to modify `dbContext.Entry(cySeMainFeatures.computer).State` directly, so the code is definitely doing something wrong

Comment: If you want to modify an object you already loaded, just make the modifications and call `SaveChanges`. The DbContext will detect them and save them. If the request provided the full details including the key, *don't* load the object. Just call `context.Update(newObject);` and the DbContext will start tracking the object in the *Modified* state if it has a PK value, or `Added` if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you're receiving indicates that there are multiple instances of the `Option` entity with the same key being tracked, which EF Core does not allow.When you use `dbContext.Add(cySeMainFeatures)`, EF Core tries to add not only the `CySeMainFeatures` entity but also all its related `Option` entities to the context.Since you have multiple properties of `CySeMainFeatures` referring to the same `Option` instance (with `id = 1`), EF Core attempts to track multiple instances of the same entity, which leads to the error.

To solve this issue, you need to ensure that EF Core correctly understands that these `Option` instances are existing entities and not new ones. This is important because you want to use the existing `Option` with `id = 1` for all properties.

Load the `Option` entity with `id = 1` from the database once and reuse it for all the properties of `CySeMainFeatures`.

```
var defaultOption = dbContext.Options.Find(1); // Assuming 'Options' is your DbSet
   if (defaultOption == null)
   {
       // Handle the case where the option does not exist
   }

   // Now use this defaultOption for all properties
   cySeMainFeatures.networkConnected = defaultOption;
   cySeMainFeatures.networkLevel = defaultOption;
   // ... Set this for all other properties
```

Since you're now using the same instance of `Option` that EF Core is already tracking, you don't need to set the state of each property to `EntityState.Unchanged`.When adding or updating `CySeMainFeatures`, EF Core will recognize that the `Option` entities are already being tracked and won't attempt to add them again.Make sure that the `Option` with `id = 1` exists in the database before running this code.

Comment: Thank you Sir, this helped me to get the right code. - I will update my post with the fix