# Entity Tracking Conflict when Authenticating Users in ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core API for user authentication, and I'm encountering an issue regarding entity tracking conflict. Here's a breakdown of my setup:

I have a method called Token in my AccountController responsible for handling user authentication. Within this method, I call another method named CheckUserWithPassword to authenticate the user.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/api/login")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Token(LoginDto postModel)
{
    var userResult = await CheckUserWithPassword(postModel);
    // Rest of the implementation
}

private async Task<int> CheckUserWithPassword(LoginDto model)
{
    
            var user = await _userService.GetUser(model.Username);
            if (user == null)
                throw new ClientSideException("Kullanıcı Bulunamadı");

            if (!user.IsActive)
                throw new ClientSideException("Kullanıcı aktif değil.");

            try
            {
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(model.Password);
                var passClean = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
                var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, passClean, false);
}
```

The CheckUserWithPassword method retrieves the user using _userService.GetUser(model.Username). Here's the implementation of GetUser method:

```
public async Task<AppUser> GetUser(string userName)
{
    return await _context.AppUsers
            .Include(u => u.Client)
            .Where(u => u.Email == userName)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

The GetUser method is defined in the IAppUserService interface and implemented in the AppUserService class.

```
public interface IAppUserService : IService<AppUser>
{
    Task<AppUser> GetUser(string userName);
}

public class AppUserService : Service<AppUser>, IAppUserService
{
    // Implementation details
}

public class RepoServiceModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(GenericRepository<>)).As(typeof(IGenericRepository<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Service<>)).As(typeof(IService<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>();

        var apiAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var repoAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(AppDbContext));
        var serviceAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MappingProfile));

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(apiAssembly, repoAssembly, serviceAssembly).Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Repository")).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(apiAssembly, repoAssembly, serviceAssembly).Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Service")).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}

// Inside Program.cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<DbContext,AppDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();

builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());
builder.Host.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(containerBuilder => containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new RepoServiceModule()));
```

However, when attempting to authenticate a user, I encounter the following error:

"The instance of entity type 'AppUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values."

It seems like the conflict arises when attempting to track multiple instances of AppUser. How can I resolve this issue to successfully authenticate users without encountering this tracking conflict? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Try putting `AsNoTracking` first, so `_context.AppUsers.AsNoTracking()...`. Also check how  your user service is registered. If it is registered as a singleton, that could be a problem.

Comment: @JackA. Despite attempting to use .AsNoTracking() in the GetUser method, the issue persists.

Comment: I tested with your code but unfortunately it is not a minimal reproducible sample. I found some discussions about the same issue which is having Scope and AsNoTracking set correctly, the attribute might cause problems. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48202403/instance-of-entity-type-cannot-be-tracked-because-another-instance-with-same-key Could you check if it is the issue and provide more details?

Comment: First, please confirm that the error is happening in the call to `_userService.GetUser` in your `CheckUserWithPassword` method. I see that your services are registered as scoped. When I have run into the "already tracked" error, it has been caused by some other code in the same scope loading the entity with tracking. Is it possible that you have middleware that is loading that entity? Maybe try putting a breakpoint in the `GetUser` method to see where it is called from. Also check for other methods that could be loading the same entity.