Error in Entity Framework Core: Instance of entity type 'ProductOrder' cannot be tracked due to duplicate key value
I'm encountering an issue with Entity Framework Core while working on an ASP.NET Core application. Specifically, I'm getting the following error message:

The instance of entity type 'ProductOrder' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ProductID', 'OrderID', 'VariantID'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Here's the relevant portion of my code where the error occurs:
[HttpPut("Update-Order/{orderId}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateOrder(int orderId, [FromBody] OrderRequestBodyDto orderRequestBody)
{
    try
    {
        // Code omitted for brevity

        // 2 - We delete the Products in the order
        await _orderService.DeleteProductOrderAsync(orderModel.productsOrder);

        // 3 - Recreate the Products in the order
        await _orderService.CreateOrderWithProductsAsync(orderId, orderRequestBody.products.ToList());

        // Code omitted for brevity
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Error handling code omitted for brevity
    }
}

I have ensured that my services are registered as transient, as shown below:
// Order Services
builder.Services.AddTransient<IOrderRepository, SqlOrderRepo>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IOrderValidationRepository, SqlOrderValidationRepo>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<OrderService>();

Despite this setup, I'm still encountering the error mentioned above. I'm not sure why the context instance is causing this issue, especially since I'm using services with transient lifetime.
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

EntityFramework populates the ID "by-Itself". You do not have to set it.
When you create new Data, fill all the Properties, except for the ID (which is marked as Primary-Key), then save the Data to the Database (using EF), and the Id's/Keys will be filled.
The Error you get is because you try to insert Data with the same Key as other Data in the Dataset alredy have.
I.E. there is a DataModel with ID 0 and you try to Add a new DataModel (with ID 0), then you get the Error (Simplyfied).

Have you check this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48202403/instance-of-entity-type-cannot-be-tracked-because-another-instance-with-same-key  ? Try to  register your service  .AddScoped<..>.

We dont see the code of these two methods but I assume the problem is happening because you are relying on changetracker and you have two separate "units of work" where you are performing database operations, and you call the second  method before calling SaveChanges so the changetracker is still remembering the same object during second method call which causes the problem. The problem could be fixed by encapsulating these method calls inside a transaction and calling SaveChanges in between method calls. this would also ensure atomicity (which you would want to have in place anyways, regardless of this specific issue).
Note that I assume _orderService has access to the same DbContext. The code would look something like this:
[HttpPut("Update-Order/{orderId}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateOrder(int orderId, [FromBody] OrderRequestBodyDto orderRequestBody)
{
    using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            await _orderService.DeleteProductOrderAsync(orderModel.productsOrder);
            _context.SaveChanges();  
            await _orderService.CreateOrderWithProductsAsync(orderId, orderRequestBody.products.ToList());
            _context.SaveChanges();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Error updating order with ID: {OrderId}", orderId);
            transaction.Rollback();
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "An error occurred while updating the order.");
        }
    }

    return Ok();
}

Clarification: calling SaveChanges in between methods releases the changetracker's memory, and since it is encapsulated in a transaction, atomicity is guaranteed (so if something goes wrong in 2nd method, the first SaveChanges will be reverted). SaveChanges() does temporarily reflect the changes to db, but the changes are not permanent until transaction is committed.
Considerations: you might possibly run into problems with the locking mechanism at the database in future. You might want to reconsider how you are updating an order. Why exactly do you have to delete an order and recreate it just to update it? What's with that? Also, how are you supposed to create a new entry with a specific ID? The database won't allow that unless you do some specific configuration.

Another way to solve the issue would be to use the newer bulk delete method of EF called ExecuteDelete so you did not rely on EF Core's change tracker in the first method (which would involve updating the current code of first method). This way, you would not have to call SaveChanges inbetween method calls, but you still would want to create a transsaction scope. What I suggested is probably simpler and will require less changes to current code.
