# How to return object from list as value

Tags: c#, list

I have a prop List<User> Users and I want to get the User that has the specified id without getting the reference to it. 
In UserDAO:

```
public User ReturnUser(int id)
{
    var q = this.Users.Where(x => x.Id == id);
    return q.ToList()[0];
}
```

In main:

```
User newUser = ud.ReturnUser(0);

Console.WriteLine(newUser.Name);
newUser.Name = "john";
Console.WriteLine(ud.Users[0].Name);
```

Comment: Are intending to make a copy of the object to modify without altering the original?

Comment: You could make `ReturnUser()` more simple with something like this: `return this.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);`

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do @Matt

Comment: Then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-net-c-specifically

Comment: @NetMage I want to make a copy of the object to modify without altering the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your User object contains only primitive properties, you could add this method:

```
public User ShallowCopy(){
  return (User)this.MemberwiseClone();
}
```

And then do this:

```
//note: no error handling if ID not found
public User ReturnUser(int id)
{
  return this.Users.Single(x => x.Id == id).ShallowCopy();

}
```

If your user contains complex type properties, you'd have to implement a deep copy if you didn't want those properties to just be references

[The fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=netframework-4.8) has a reasonable amount to say and some good examples

Answer (score 1):

First of all use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `Where()` if you are going to take only the first match.

And secondly, you can just return a Clone of the result:

```
public User ReturnUser(int id)
{
    var q = this.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    return q?.MemberwiseClone();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `AsNoTracking()` might be the way you want to go.

```
public User ReturnUser(int id)
{
    return this.Users.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

This link has more information on `AsNoTracking()` but the above should achieve what you're looking to accomplish.

[What difference does .AsNoTracking() make?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211680/what-difference-does-asnotracking-make)

Answer (score 0):

Try This, But be careful this will only work if your user object contains only primitive type such as int, double, bool and not reference types.

For Deep Copy/Deep Clone see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var users = new List<User>()
        {
            new User()
            {
                Name = "My Name",
                Job = new Job()
                {
                    Title = "Developer"
                }
            }
        };

        var clonedUser = users[0].Clone();

        clonedUser.Name = "My Updated Name";
        clonedUser.Job.Title = "Graphic Designer"; //This Won't Work

        Console.WriteLine(users[0].Name);
        Console.WriteLine(users[0].Job.Title);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Job Job { get; set; }

    public User Clone()
    {
        return (User) this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}

public class Job
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```