# Is AsNoTracking() redundant?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a question want to ask about AsNoTracking() method of EF
I've write code:

```
await _context.Company.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

My purpose is want to this code will return an list, with AsNoTracking() is make EF doesn't track it, because list is read-only
But, my Leader said remove "AsNoTracking()" because it is redundant.
So, maybe i wrong understand, i hope you help me understand about it
Thank

Comment: If you are not going to modify entities use `AsNoTracking()` to avoid tracking mechanism overhead.

Comment: Unless this is applied elsewhere, it is not redundant

Comment: If you will never call `SaveChanges()`, using `AsNoTracking()` in query you will get better efficiency.

refer to:
[MSDN - Tracking vs. No-Tracking Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking)
and
[What difference does .AsNoTracking() make?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22807021/15422161)